# Getting One email alert for all Ansible hosts

Tags: linux, automation, ansible, redhat

I have written one simple playbook for getting server versions on my mailbox. But the problem is that I receive separate email for every server. This floods my mailbox. Is there any way by which we can get single email for all the hosts?

```yaml
- name: Test Playbook
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Check Version
      shell: cat '/etc/redhat-release'
      register: ver
    - debug:
      var: ver
    - name: Email the scan report
      mail:
        from: server@email.com
        to: user@email.com
        subject: Testing Mail
        body: Version is "{{ ansible_hostname }}{{ ver.stdout_lines }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Fit the body to your needs

```yaml
    - name: Email the scan report
      mail:
        from: server@email.com
        to: user@email.com
        subject: Testing Mail
        body: |
          Versions:
          {% for host in ansible_play_hosts %}
          {{ host }} {{ hostvars[host].ver.stdout_lines }}
          {% endfor %}
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

Notes:

- See [special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)
- See [Jinja](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#)